# UICollectionViewCell's alpha property doesn't take effect until reloaded?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

If I set a cell's alpha property in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` as follows...

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CGPathCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
// Prepare cell
cell.alpha = 0.5
cell.setNeedsDisplay()
return cell
}
```

...the cells that initially appear are opaque (alpha of 1.0).  If I scroll, the "new" (reused) cells that appear have the expected alpha value.  If I scroll back to the beginning, the "original" cells (which began opaque) now also have the expected alpha value.

Why is the alpha value not set when it is initially loaded?

**Additional attempts that don't work:**

1. Adding this to the delegate, I get the same result:

   ```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       cell.alpha = 0.5
   }
   ```
2. Adding this to `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   let attrs = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
   attrs.alpha = 0.5
   cell.applyLayoutAttributes(attrs)
   ```

Comment: try adding cell.needsDisplay = true. This could force the cell to redraw itself.

Comment: and you should cast your cell as your cell class `as UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Good thought, @user965972, but actually when I add this line before `return cell` I get the same result.  Will edit the question.

Comment: @Bluehound took that out for brevity--have edited the question.

Comment: I thought it could have caused a problem if your code actually neglected to include it because without it, cell is AnyObject

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Actually, I never did--I was going to use the effect to show which cell was selected, but because I couldn't get it working a ended up using another effect entirely.  I'm not sure if the question should be deleted or not.

Comment: So why not just call `collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(_:)` for the indexPath of the cell you'd you like to apply the effect to?

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is happening because Apple is doing some special internal handling with the cell as part of a `UICollectionView`. If you set the alpha on the cell's **`contentView`** property, the alpha persists as expected.

The [UICollectionViewCell docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewCell/contentView) *kind of* hint at this:

> To configure the appearance of your cell, add the views needed to present the data item’s content as subviews to the view in the contentView property. Do not directly add subviews to the cell itself.

If you have a `backgroundView` or `selectedBackgroundView`, you'll need to set their alphas separately.

Comment: Interesting!  I'll give this a try later today and get back to you--thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I had a simliar problem some time ago with resizing a pdf, it was likely the same. I solved it in the following way, every time the pdf was had to be resized setNeedsDisplay doesn't work, so i made an ViewController, which alpha: 0 and call an non animated segue to this view controller, so that the clear view controller was over the view controller i wanted to update, after this i immediately dismissed the new view controller, so the pdf was updated to the new size. Also this question is quite old maybe this helps you to solve your problem.